# What is the capacitance of a spoon?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance, conductors, estimation

Has anyone measured it? I can't seem to find anything online for "spoon capacitance"; what's the expected (self-)capacitance on the typical household utility metal spoon? The spoon heads bear a nice surface area to store charges like a two-plate capacitor.

Alternatively, capacitance of any typical household utility will also do (fork, knife, metal fry pan...).

Comment: You can measure this yourself -- most (all?) modern digital multimeters can measure capacitance. To measure self-capacitance, simply ground the other lead.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Really? Mine certainly can't. I needed to get a separate LCR meter to be able to do that. (I was just trying it out myself when I saw your comment ;) )

Comment: @Philip It looks like a better qualifier would be "many". It does look like entry-level ones can't, but there are multiple search results on Amazon that spec that ability.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I think entry-level describes mine pretty well :P I'd be curious to know if anyone has a way to do this without a fancier one, given the current lockdown situation. It's an interesting question.

Comment: My analog multimeter (V/A/Ω) cost nine dollars. My most recent digital multimeter cost nineteen dollars and has a mode for measuring capacitance, a six-hole input for measuring the orientation and gain of a three-pin transistor, and an input for a thermocouple (and came with about a meter of thermocouple wire ready to use). I would certainly consider nineteen dollars an entry-level price. I would say the correct statement is "it's still possible to buy multimeters that don't measure capacitance."

Comment: @rob My multimeter's 20 USD and doens't measure C; in fact my University lab multimeters, 100+ USD, also didn't measure it - only the 200 USD Fluke meters did. If anyone here's willing to zap a spoon, could earn themselves a quick +25 from me.

Comment: There are good reasons why Fluke hardware costs ten times as much as Harbor Freight hardware that has the same list of functions, but that's a discussion for another venue.

Comment: Capacitance is distance (i.e. one system of units might give capacitance in units identical to length, i.e. centimeters).   So, it will depend on the size of the spoon, and to some extent, the shape.   Alas, a common teaspoon is lower capacitance than most measuring instruments can handle, electrical-testing style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Gary Godfrey beat me to the spherical cow joke](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/574781/81133).  For a slightly more sophisticated theorist's answer, let's consider an ellipsoidal cow instead.  According to the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.33#ii), the inverse of the capacitance of an conducting ellipsoid with semi-major axes $a$, $b$, and $c$ is $\frac{1}{C} = R_F(a^2, b^2, c^2) / (4 \pi \epsilon_0)$, where
$$
R_F(a^2, b^2, c^2) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t+a^2)(t+b^2)(t+c^2)}}.
$$
(Note that the formula given in the above link is in CGS units;  I think I have correctly converted it to MKS units, but let me know if this needs correction.)
This integral doesn't have a closed-form expression for arbitrary $a$, $b$, and $c$;  but for $a = b < c$, it can be performed:
$$
R_F(a^2, a^2, c^2) = \frac{\cosh^{-1} (c/a)}{\sqrt{c^2 - a^2}}.
$$
This implies that
$$
C = 4 \pi \epsilon_0 \frac{\sqrt{c^2 - a^2}}{\cosh^{-1} (c/a)}.
$$
If we approximate a spoon as an ellipsoid of length 20 cm and diameter 2 cm, we have $c = 10$ cm and $a = 1$ cm, and we obtain $ C \approx 3.7$ pF.

As another example, if we approximate a human body as an ellipsoid with $c = 80$ cm and $a = 20$ cm, we obtain $C \approx 42$ pF.  We can see that this is within an order of magnitude of [estimates found elsewhere.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/574730/81133)

For an object that is better approximated as an oblate ellipsoid, with $a = b > c$, the integral is slightly different, and the capicatnce turns out to be:
$$
C = 4 \pi \epsilon_0 \frac{\sqrt{a^2 - c^2}}{\cos^{-1} (c/a)}.
$$
If a frying pan has a radius of $c \approx 15$ cm, and a thickness of about 4 cm (so $a \approx 2 cm$), then $C \approx 11.5 pF$.  Still smaller than that of a human body.

Finally, note that in both cases, for a given ratio of $c/a$, the capacitance of a body scales linearly with its size.  This is a general property that can (I think) be proven rigorously for bodies of arbitary shape via arguments based on the properties of Laplace's equation.

Comment: Props for answering both questions. If anyone actually measures a spoon's capacitance, do post, I'll upvote. Imaginary bonus pts for measuring several spoons.

Comment: Also, assuming 4pF is accurate, then I should be able to take 20 spoons and half the volts - not bad. If that's the spoon's, then a frying pan's or cooking pot's must be much greater - so you _can_ ground yourself to household utensils after all.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon:  Again, the capacitance of an object scales roughly with its linear size, not with its mass.  A frying pan might weigh 100 times more than a spoon, but its capacitance will not be 100 times greater.  I'll do a quick calculation to show this.

Comment: I didn't mean mass, but its surface area, which is easily dozens times greater

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon:  Fair enough, but my point still stands.  An object with twice the linear size has four times the surface area, but only twice the capacitance.

Comment: You obtained frying pan's capacitance only 3.1x greater? Your assumed 15cm radius is incidentally exactly what I just measured on my frying pan, and the thing's huge - 4cm is also accurate for height. Moreover, an ellipsoid seems overly hand-wavy; a spoon is more like a wide rod + hemi-ellipsoid. I can wager the pan's surface area being 50x+ greater, and with the perhaps more accurate representation of 2D ellipses, this gives us sqrt(50) = 7x.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the old physics joke of "consider a spherical cow", let's consider a spherical spoon of radius r.  The capacitance of a sphere in outer space is

\begin{align}
C_\text{sphere} &= 4\pi \epsilon_0 r=4\pi\times 8.8\times10^{-12} \frac{\rm F}{\rm m} \times r
\\ &=111.\times 10^{-12} \frac{\rm F}{\rm m} \times r
\\ &\approx 1~\mathrm{pF}\times \frac{r}{\rm \text{cm}}
\end{align}

My spoon is 16 cm long (ie: a spherical spoon of 8 cm radius), so the spoon's capacitance is approximately 8 pf.